# Ruby on Rails Installation Error on CYGWIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install rails on CYGWIN and I obtained the following error:

```
$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
can't convert nil into String
```

How I can I eliminate this error and enjoy the wonders of Ruby on Rails

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't install ruby on rails. TypeError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288232/cant-install-ruby-on-rails-typeerror)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know reason why latest version from http://rubygems.org doesn't work with cygwin. I use [this](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/archive/v1.8.24.zip) older version from [github repo](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases).