# Can't install ruby on rails. TypeError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cygwin, installation, typeerror

I'm trying to install ruby on rails for windows 7. I've tried this on Professional and Enterprise.

I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial if it helps answer this question.
First I install Cygwin64, then I download rubygems-2.3.0. I move rubygems-2.3.0 into C:\cygwin64\home\mycomputername. I untar it successfully, cd into the rubygems-2.3.0 folder, and run setup.rb.
Everything works fine up till here.

When I run the command gem install rails --version 3.0.0, it installs successfully until I get to

Fetching: rack-1.2.8.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    can't convert nil into String

Which is where the above error happens. After this, no rails command will work.

I should note that my version of ruby is v1.9.3, if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you install Ruby and Rails from http://railsinstaller.org/en if you are on Windows 7.

Comment: Ok, so I did that, and I was able to create a new rails app. When I close that command line environment I can't get it back. It says it's just normal win32 cmd, but it has linux commands. Could you tell me how to get that environment back without having to reinstall every time?

Comment: Never mind. It's under start menu under the rails installer folder. Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows it's best to use [railsinstaller.org](http://railsinstaller.org). If you could install Linux it would be a better option for developing ruby on rails.